# Testing JWT Authentication with mock JWT token

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, junit5

I'm writing jUnit test to test my resource server's endpoints.
Now these endpoints are protected via @PreAuthorized (and similar) annotation like the one below:

```java
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('SCOPE_data.write')")
@PostMapping("/save")
public ResponseEntity<Book> saveBook(
        @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody(
                description = "Save book",
                required = true,
                content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = Book.class))) 
        @Valid @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody Book book){
    try {
        Book _book = bookRepo.save(new Book(book.getID(), vehicle.getTitle(), vehicle.getAuthor()));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(_book, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

My unit test will be like:

```java
@Test
public void testSaveBook() throws Exception {
        
    this.mockMvc.perform(
            post("/book/save")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(bookToSave))
        .with(jwt().authorities(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("SCOPE_data.write")))
        .andDo(print())
        .andExpect(status().isOk));
}
```

And this is my SecurityConfig:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests(exchanges -> exchanges
            .antMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated())
        .csrf().disable()
        .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));
    return http.build();
}
```

My concern is about the *jwt()* instruction. Like it is written in the official [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/servlet/test/mockmvc/oauth2.html#_jwt_requestpostprocessor) this instruction will create a jwt token with ***"headers" : { "alg" : "none" }***


My **questions** are the following:

  
1. Why my endpoint is accessible with this token? And why my resource server accept this token?

2. With this token any user can access my endpoint, and so have access to the data inside the database?

3. Are there any security problems concerning the use of this token?

4. Is there any filter to insert inside a FilterChain?

Can anyone answer my questions and clear my doubts?

   
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The `jwt()` method in the `MockMvc` test DSL (domain-specific language) is used for mocking JWT authentication in your tests. Let's answer your questions one by one:

1. **Why is my endpoint accessible with this token? And why does my resource server accept this token?**

   When you're using `jwt().authorities(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("SCOPE_data.write"))` in the context of a `MockMvc` test, you're essentially creating a mocked (simulated) JWT authentication for testing. It bypasses the normal JWT processing and validation (signature, expiration, issuer, etc.) and directly simulates a user authenticated with a JWT that has the given authorities. It's just for testing; in a real-world scenario, the actual JWT would be processed and validated according to your resource server's configuration.
2. **With this token, can any user access my endpoint and therefore access the data inside the database?**

   No, real users cannot use the "alg: none" token in a production environment to access your endpoints. This is a testing mechanism that's only valid within the confines of the `MockMvc` framework. In production, the token would be rejected because it's unsigned. It's worth noting that allowing "none" as an algorithm in real JWT processing is a security risk, but this isn't what's happening here. This is only for test scenarios.
3. **Are there any security problems concerning the use of this token?**

   As long as this mocked JWT authentication is used strictly within the confines of your test environment and never in production, there should be no security concerns. This is a utility provided by Spring Security for testing purposes. You're essentially saying, "Let's pretend we have a valid JWT with these authorities and see how the system behaves."

However, a few best practices and additional notes:

- Ensure you don't use the "none" algorithm or similar insecure configurations in your production JWT processing.
- Always keep your test configurations separate from your production configurations to avoid potential security pitfalls.
- Regularly review and update your security configurations and dependencies to stay updated with security best practices and patches.

Finally, while your test is checking for `status().isOk`, the actual endpoint returns a `HttpStatus.CREATED` (201) when a book is saved. You might want to update your test to check for `status().isCreated()` instead of `isOk()` to more accurately reflect expected behavior.

Comment: is there any official documentation where I can find all this informations?  1. Ok, thanks for the explanation.  2. So, if I still use my production DB inside the unit test, there isn't any problems. Am I right? Or should I must configure another datasource?  3. Perfect.  Thanks for the additional notes. No, my auth server doesn't have none as an option. Yes, I have copy/paste my code and I forgot to change the expected status. I'm going to change it.

Comment: You should separate test and production environment databases and 3rd party services.

Comment: For more mastery, you can use the following refrence:
https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-series

Comment: Ok, but in that link I cannot found anything about mocking jwt...

Comment: This article should help you: 
https://medium.com/@nsready/mock-jwt-oauth2-authentication-fcdc209e522b

Comment: Also you use this sample code:
https://medium.com/@nsready/mock-jwt-oauth2-authentication-fcdc209e522b

Comment: Ok, thanks but this is not what I'm looking for.